# Unable to make a range of dummy files

Tags: bash, terminal

I need to make files called from File1, File2, ... to File99.

I tried the following unsuccessfully

```
cat test > {File1 .. File99}
```

The command without the word File did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just one command:

```
touch File{1..99}
```

Comment: Concise.  I presumed you WANTED the contents of file "test" in the new files.

Comment: You can use {01..99} to have File01, File02, etc.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do touch "File$i"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

This will depend on the shell you are using. I assume you are using Bash.

According to http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion, Bash will expand digits and single characters. So your brace expression should be:

```
File{1..99}
```

But I don't think the redirection operator ">" can output to multiple files. You might need to use a loop:

```
for output in File{1..99}
do
    cat test > $output
done
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
for output in File{1..99}; do cat test > $output; done
```

Comment: I tried your command as a one-liner unsuccessfully: $ for output in File{1..99}; do; cat test > $output; done

Comment: I think you have an extra semicolon. The following works for me:

    for output in File{1..99}; do cat test > $output; done

Comment: It works with $ for output in File{1..99}; do cat test > $output; done

Comment: I like also a combination of your and Bryan's codes like $ for i in {1..99}; do cat test > File$i; done

Comment: I wonder how you could make the same code in Python as a one-liner. It could be even shorter.

Comment: I dont know. here's a shot: """t=open("test","rb").read(); [open("File%d"%(i,),"wb").write(t) for i in range(1,100)]"""

Comment: """import shutil; [shutil.copy("test", "File%d"%(i,)) for i in range(1,100)]"""

Comment: @Joe: I did not get the Python code to work. Could you please dpaste the code.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer a non looping version then you can use tee

```
cat test | tee File{1..99} > /dev/null
```

Comment: @Masi: Mostly to be equivalent with the other answers. Another possible reason, although not mine, is to prevent a long output that isn't needed.

Comment: 'tee' would otherwise copy the output to the terminal as well as the files.

Answer (score 3):

With *zsh* (with its *mult_ios*) you can :)

```
% zsh -c 'print test > file{1..3}' 
% head file*                      
==> file1 <==
test

==> file2 <==
test

==> file3 <==
test
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the files to sort properly (file01, file02 ... file10, etc.), do this:

```
for i in {0..10}; do i="0"$i; touch file${i: -2}; done
```

Which is the same as:

```
for i in {0..10}
do
    i="0"$i
    touch file${i: -2} # or cat file > file${i: -2}
done
```

There must be be a space between the colon and the dash in the substring expansion clause. You can start the ranges above with 1 if you want to start with "file01".

Or, a much more succinct way to have leading zeros:

```
touch file{0..9}{0..9}
```

and to use phyrex1an's technique with this one:

```
cat test | tee File{0..9}{0..9} > /dev/null
```

This does make one extra file "file00". You can also do "{2..3}{0..9}" for "file20" through "file39", but changing the ones digit (the second range) would cause parts of the sequence to be skipped.